# how to make keyboard shortcut with key "c" from keyboard for calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am wondering if it is possible to call a jquery function from keyboard key.

Say i want to clear textbox values , if users press "c" key from her keyboard.

Now i am  calling a function onclick event.Same function i want to call if users press "c" key from keyboard

```
  $(".clear").click(function()
        { 
            $('#from_amount').val(''); 
            $('#to_amount').val(''); 
            $('.clear').hide(); 
        });
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event to handle this.

One possible problem with this will be, you won't be able to press `c` anywhere in the document, so you may want to support a key combination like `ctrl + c`. Or do not want to do this when the key is pressed within a input field

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which == 99){
                    $('#from_amount').val(''); 
                    $('#to_amount').val(''); 
                    $('.clear').hide(); 
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Ignoring keypress from input fields

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which==99 && !$(e.target).is(':input')){
                console.log('clear')
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: would be exceptionally funny if the user was in focus of the textbox when this listener fired

Comment: @KaiQing User will be foolish if they enters alphabets  as amount -:)

Comment: If there's anything you learn about web development over the years is that the user is ALWAYS foolish. Anyhow, couldn't you also call $('.clear').click() to fire off the click listener

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you write your answer code inside `<script> .....</script>` Because i am confused where should i keep your code, either in the ready function or somehere else

Comment: @ArunPJohny you have written two scripts, which one is correct?

Comment: I've explained in the answer how it works, you can choose which ever you want

Comment: @ArunPJohny well, i tried the first one . I am getting one problem. If  I enter  value in the textbox ,and if i  press "c" then its clearing previous enter value but its printing "c" in my textbox. I do not want to print c value, because it is for clearing the field...